# Is the series $\sum \frac{3 + \sin n}{n^2}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

How can I show if the following series converges?

$$\sum \frac{3 + \sin n}{n^2}$$

I can't use differential or integral calculus (hasn't been covered in my class yet.)

Comment: What can you use?

Comment: Since $|\sin x|\leq1$ then $\dfrac{3+\sin n}{n^2}\leq\dfrac{3}{n^2}$, what do you can say about $\displaystyle\sum\frac{3}{n^2}$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Convergence tests, such as the Dirichlet's, Cauchy Condensation, etc., or just general rules about series, sequences and limits of sequences.

Comment: @DiegoMath If you mean the $\frac{3}{n^2}$ then I know that that one is convergent (as it's a form of the zeta function?)

Comment: @DiegoMath: shouldn't that be $\dfrac{4}{n^2}$?

Comment: Well $\sum\frac{k}{n^2}$ is convergent for all finite $k$

Comment: @kingW3 yes! Thanks guys, I totally understand now. I'll accept the answer as soon as the SE timer allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $-1 \le \sin n \le 1$ for all $n$.

Use this to show that $\dfrac{3+\sin n}{n^2}$ is non-negative, and compare it with the series $\dfrac{4}{n^2}$.

Comment: Oh perfect :) So I can basically ignore the numerator, since it is within the bounds of $[2,4]$, and just say that it is convergent because $1/n^2$ converges, right?

Comment: Actually, what you are doing is using the basic comparison test to compare the given series to a series which is known to converge.

Answer (score 0):

Since $-1\le \sin n \le 1$, we have $\frac{2}{n^2} \le \frac{3+\sin n}{n^2} \le \frac{4}{n^2}$. Hence, try comparing your series to $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{4}{n^2}$, both of which converge.